# Do I need to place entire database in Parse.com

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, push-notification, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

We are using [OpenMRS](http://openmrs.org/) in Amazon EC2 .Can the Parse.com to make only notifications database or The Entire database to be build on Parse.com.
If it is So.We will be using the Google Messaging Cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse's push offering can be augmented with other features (i.e. advanced targeting based on relationships with users or other data stored with Parse), but it is designed to work as a standalone feature.

Comment: You can use parse for push without using parse for data.